# Controller Net Core 3 with Entity Framework and SQL Server DB. Error in date/time conversion

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When my controller execute this LINQ selection code

```
List<Order> list = _salesContext.Orders
                                .Where(o => o.Date >= new DateTime(2019, 1, 1))
                                .Take(10)
                                .OrderBy(o => o.Date)
                                .ToList();
```

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How can I solve this problem?

If I use

```
_salesContext.Orders
             .Where(o => o.Date.Year >= 2019 && o.Date.Month >= 1 && o.Date.Day >= 1))
```

it works fine.

Comment: I verified SQL query generated. The WHERE with Date filter is
    WHERE [e].[Date] >= '2019-01-01T00:00:00.0000000'
but Sql Server need WHERE [e].[Date] >= '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000'
with only milliseconds (3 zero)

Comment: I solved changing Date type in database from datetime to datetime2. I will change all date columns to datetime2.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue when i use the type of datetime in database.But actually it would generate the type of datetime2(7) in database by default when i create model  and scafold the database in .net core 3.0.What is your model like?

Comment: I have an older database created over ten years ago and populated with hundreds of data. Today CRUD operation is performed via legacy SOAP webservice. I'm building a web api net core 3 to replace it.

Comment: @StefanoGardini did you found a answer for this question?

Comment: I solved only changing date type in DB.

Answer (score 1):

Every SQL client sends datetime to the SQL client as a string. Given error says that datetime string, that EntityFramework provide (send in query actually) to your SQL server, can't be cast to the SQL datetime - so you have to check you SQL user (or application) localization settings (becase datetame in such localization is required by SQL server) - you have to chceck your application / sql user localization settings.

[image: SQL user language]

Comment: Application and SQL Server are both in Italian language/localization. Thanks but this isn't a solution for me.

Comment: Try to login to SQL Management Studio with same credentials you use in .NET application connection string. Then also run SQL profiler and look for your query. Copy it, and try to run the query in Management Studio - I am almost sure that it's a problem. BTW. What do you mean by "Application in Itialian language"? Is your Thread culture set corretly ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. In my case was because my date column allow null values. And when I select any row that had a null value at date column I get the same exception you get.

I solved my problem using a null able datetime property in my class.

```
 public DateTime? Date {get; set;}
```

Then

```
_salesContext.Orders
.Where(o => o.Date.HasValue && o.Date >= new DateTime(2019, 1, 1)                    
.Take(10)                        
.OrderBy(o => o.Data)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but in my case Date non allow NULL value. I attempt to set nullable value in model but it does not work

Comment: If you do a select direct in SQL server table is there any null value on datetime column?

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't provide info on your database and how you're structuring Orders, I wrote something that works as a charm and might be helpful for you to figure out what's wrong. Don't forget to migrate.

*********** Order ************

```
public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

*********** Database ************

```
public class SalesDBContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Testing;Integrated Security=True");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
```

*********** Program ************

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(var _salesContext = new SalesDBContext())
            {
                _salesContext.Orders.Add(new Order()
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now,
                    Name = "Now"
                });
                _salesContext.Orders.Add(new Order()
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 1),
                    Name = "Problem"
                });
                _salesContext.Orders.Add(new Order()
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(2019, 5, 5),
                    Name = "Problem2"
                });
                _salesContext.Orders.Add(new Order()
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(2017, 10, 20),
                    Name = "Old"
                });
                _salesContext.SaveChanges();
                var orders = _salesContext.Orders
                                         .Where(o => o.Date > new DateTime(2019, 1, 1))
                                         .Take(2).OrderBy(o => o.Date)
                                         .ToList();
                foreach(var order in orders)
                    Console.WriteLine(order.Name);
            }
        }
```

*********** Result ************

**Problem**

**Now**